# how to restrict instances in drop down

Tags: grails, scaffolding

I'm having an instance form which contains a template and an appearance.
To create a new form, I have a view with 2 dropdown which contains the templates and appearances. Now I want to restrict the templates and appearances to those owned by the curren logged in user.

I'm using the tostring method to format the dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, you would want to query for the authenticated user's data.  Assuming your Template.groovy looks something like this:

```
class Template {
  String name
  static belongsTo = [owner: User]
}
```

Then in your controller's action:

```
def create() {
   def authenticatedUser = .... // however you get the logged in user
   def templates = Template.findAllByOwner(authenticatedUser)
   [templates: templates]
}
```

And then in your create.gsp:

```
<g:select from="${templates} ... />
```

Obviously, doing the same thing for Appearance.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer! It increased my vision on the whole Grails story.